# DataGridView.Clear()

Tags: c#, .net

Here comes the trouble.
I want to delete all rows from datagridview.
This how i add rows:

```
private void ReadCompleteCallback(object clientHandle, Opc.Da.ItemValueResult[]     results)
{
    foreach (Opc.Da.ItemValueResult readResult in results)
    {
        dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => dataGridView1.Rows.Add(readResult.ItemName, readResult.Quality, readResult.Timestamp,readResult.Value)));        
    }
}
```

And its how i clear gridview:

```
private void treeView1_SelectionsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    items = new Opc.Da.Item[treeView1.SelectedNodes.Count]; 
    foreach (TreeNode x in treeView1.SelectedNodes) {
        items[treeView1.SelectedNodes.IndexOf(x)] = new Opc.Da.Item();
        items[treeView1.SelectedNodes.IndexOf(x)].ItemName = x.Text; 
    }

    group.AddItems(items);
    group.Read(group.Items, 123, new Opc.Da.ReadCompleteEventHandler(ReadCompleteCallback), out req);
}
```

in debug i see that dataGridVIew1.Rows.Count=0, but on form, grid doesnt become clear. what a point?
on each selection in tree, i want to see new rows in table.

Comment: That seems a very odd time to clear it, and I expect that ties into the issue. What are you trying to do here, for interest?

Comment: ok, I see - that makes more sense now. Trying to think why this would behave like that.

Comment: Why dont you use a DataSource with a BindingList instead?

Comment: hm.. i dont have datasource. data taken from opc server.

Comment: but thats good idea, ill try to do it

Answer (score 159, accepted):

I'm betting you just need to refresh the datagrid. Try this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

If this works... you might want to rethink this part of your application.

Answer (score 49):

If I remember correctly, I set the DataSource property to null to clear the DataGridView:

```
datagridview.DataSource = null;
```

Comment: this answer assumes use of data binding.  If manipulating the grid manually this will not work.  Need to do Rows.Clear() and Refresh() for manually inserted rows.  See answer by NitroxDM.

Answer (score 19):

To clear the `datagridview` write the following code:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource=null;
```

Comment: this answer assumes use of data binding.  If manipulating the grid manually this will not work.  Need to do Rows.Clear() and Refresh() for manually inserted rows.  See answer by NitroxDM.

Answer (score 10):

Basically below code line is only useful in data binding scenarios

```
datagridview.DataSource = null;
```

otherwise below is the used when no data binding and datagridview is populated manually

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

So, check first what you are doing.

Answer (score 9):

If you want clear a dataGridView not binded to DataSource but manually loaded you can use this simple code:

```
datagridview.Rows.Clear();
datagridview.Columns.Clear();
```

Answer (score 4):

all you need to do is clear your datatable before you fill it... and then just set it as you dgv's datasource

Comment: Isn't that what all the other answers are screaming..?

Comment: Not exactly.  If your data source is bound to your DataTable, then simply calling dataTable.Clear(); will get the job done in one simple step.

Answer (score 4):

I have this piece of code i hope it may help u.

```
int numRows = dgbDatos.Rows.Count;    
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
    try
    {    
        int max = dgbDatos.Rows.Count - 1;
        dgbDatos.Rows.Remove(dgbDatos.Rows[max]);

    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You can´t delete A row " + exe, "WTF",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply if your are trying to rebind your Data Grid View just code this:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet.Tables["TableName"];
```

OR

```
DataGridView.DataSource = DataTable;
```

else if you trying to to clear your Data Grid View just code this:

```
DataGridView.DataSource = null;
DataGridView.Rows.Clear();
DataGridView.Refresh();
```

and add any method or event to bind Data Grid View Again below this line of code....

Answer (score 2):

try setting RowCount to 0(allowuserstorows should be false), along with calling clear

Comment: it says that number of rows must be at least 1. but even setting it to 1 - doesnt help.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it:

```
datagridview.DataSource = null;
datagridview.Refresh();
```

I hope it works for you because it is working for me.

Comment: this answer assumes use of data binding.  If manipulating the grid manually this will not work.  Need to do Rows.Clear() and Refresh() for manually inserted rows.  See answer by NitroxDM.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
datagrid.DataSource = null;
datagrid.DataBind();
```

Basically you will need to clear the datasource your binding to the grid.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Method

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dt.Rows.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dataGridView1.DataSource=null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the datasource property to an empty string then call the Clear method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like messing with the DataSource personally so after discussing the issue with an IT friend I was able to discover this way which is simple and doesn't effect the DataSource. Hope this helps!

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) 
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cell.Value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Iteration is slow.  Try calling the row's collection Clear() method instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your `DataGridView` does not have any `DataSource` the solution does not come by manipulating it.

You will always have an `empty` row if you have the `AllowUserToAddRows` property set to `true`.

Put `AllowUserToAddRows = false` if you don't need permise this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds crazy, but I solved this issue by
changing the datagrid.visible property to false and then to true.
It causes a very small blink, but it works for me (at least for now).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the DataGridView properties and simply "refresh" it:

```cs
DataTable emptyDt = new DataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = emptyDt;
```

You could encapsulate it in a function for later use.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with data binging manually the best way to refresh datagridview is dispose the DataTable or Dataset that you used to populate the grid. otherwise how hard you try to clear the rows or remove the rows in Datagridview, it will not refresh the data grid

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (this.dgInv.DataSource != null) {
        this.dgInv.DataSource = null;
    } else {
        this.dgInv.Rows.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
DataGridView1.DataSource=ds;
ds.Clear();
```