# How can I clear rows in DataGridView with C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Following Error in this line.

```
datagridview1.Rows.Clear()
```

but this line gives error:

> Cannot clear this list.

Comment: try calling `datagridview1.bind();` after you clear rows to refresh grid. Just a guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView.Clear()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744882/datagridview-clear)

Comment: ^^ Not a possible duplicate, tried that.. but it gives a different error to what's in that post

Answer (score 26):

I also had similiar problem when I try to clear DataSource of a DataGridView after I had binded it to a DataTable with:

```
DataTable DT = ... ; // fill it
datagridview1.DataSource = DT;
```

when I try to clear it's rows later with the following code:

```
datagridview1.DataSource = null
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This object reference ERROR problem already solved in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867136/datagridview-datasource-null-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-o). But I managed to solve my own problem (clearing DataGridView rows) with this code:

```
DataTable DT = (DataTable)datagridview1.DataSource;
if (DT != null) 
    DT.Clear();
```

I know that this question was asked a very long time ago, but I hope my solution would solve someone problems.

Comment: Thank you!  Even with very old questions, a new answer might not help the OP, but it certainly helps others like me.

Comment: Worked as expected, and still retained my Column Definitions.  Used this methodology for a Refining Structure against a DGV when the user clicked the Reset Button.

Comment: This answer didn't break for me until my user started manually entering data into my datagridview.  Then I realized what I really needed to do was to initialize my datagridview datasource to a data table in an initialization step early on and then forget about it later in my code.  I set my DataTable as a member variable and let the binding keep everything in sink.  In short, initialize everything up front.  Then call .Clear(); on your data table itself.

Comment: I added a solution that doesn't involve checking nulls

Answer (score 5):

Is your `DataGridView` bound to a `DataSource`, i think thats why its not allowing you to clear it since its bound to an underlying `DataTable` or `List`.

you could try setting the DataSource Property to null

`datagridview1.DataSource = null;` for clearing

Comment: This will clear the COlumns definition as well, giving you a empty shell of a DataGridView.

Comment: its not working for me. First I set the `DataSource = null;` then them clear rows using `dgv.Rows.Clear()`. It did not work

Answer (score 5):

```
private void button_Limpar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable DT = (DataTable)dataGridView_Cidade.DataSource;
    if (DT != null)
        DT.Clear();
}
#endregion
```

Comment: dpulicate answer to @Aryo above.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add this line at beginning of your event:

```
dgv_nameOfGridView.DataSource=false;
```

Now every time you click it will erase the  dgv..

Comment: This will clear all row information and column definitions leaving a DGV shell which pretty cant be bound to with a pre-defined column definition set.

Answer (score 3):

You have to Clear datasource not datagridview rows.

```
datagridview1.DataSource = null;
```

Another way is

1) Dont assign direct datasource to gridview.
add rows from datatable to gridview

```
      foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            var dataGridRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            dataGridRow.CreateCells(datagridview1);

            for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
            {
                dataGridRow.Cells[i].Value = row.ItemArray[i];
            }

            datagridview1.Rows.Add(dataGridRow);
        }
```

then use

```
datagridview1.Rows.Clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple method:
First clear your DataTable and then refresh your DataGridView

```
dataTable.Clear();
dataGridView.Refresh();
```

Hope this help

Comment: This worked for me, because my DataTable was bound to a dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution is to clear the DataSet.
ds.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

> Since you are using a bound grid, have you tried to call your loading
>   function twice and verified that the data is not doubling?
>
> Since it is bound, loading twice ought to not duplicate the data.

http://www.vbforums.com/showpost.php?s=aa5f116586c00a2d9ea15e3727fc5c2f&p=2841192&postcount=9

Answer (score 0):

First clear  DataSource and then clear DataGridView

in  VB

```
 datagridview1.DataSource = Nothing
 datagridview1.Rows.Clear()
```

hope help

Answer (score 0):

If you load your DataGridView with a parameter, you can send an empty parameter to it. This will clear your DataGridView without having to set its DataSet to null.

For example, I load my DataGridView with a Code, when I fill a TextBox.

```
this.dataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.ds_MyDataSet.DataTable1, TextBox1.Text);
```

If I want to clear its content, then

```
this.dataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.ds_MyDataSet.DataTable1, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we are 8 years later.

Although

```
datagridview1.DataSource = null;
```

is a satisfactory answer for most, for me this removes all customizations I've added to the columns in design view. So hidden columns appears if I want to clear out the rows.

So rather than clear out rows:

```
datagridview1.Rows.Clear()
```

Clear out the DataTable or DataView that you used to set up the DataGridView. Note you don't have to check if something is null nor worry about Object not set to reference errors.

So here's how I did mine:

```
//Populate the datagridview
DataTable _DT = new DataTable();
BindingSource _BS = new BindingSource();

//Initially fill up your datatable with stuff
//You can call this method again if data needed to be changed
public void fillDT(int id) {
    _DT = fillUpDataTableWithStuffFromDB(id);

    _BS.DataSource = _DT.DefaultView;
    datagridview1.DataSource = _BS;
    _BS.ResetBindings(false);
}

//You can use this method to mimic the functionality above
//But rather fetching data, just clear out the datatable and pass it in
public void clearDT() {
    _DT.Clear();
    datagridview1.DataSource = _DT.DefaultView;
    datagridview1.Refresh();
}
```

As you can see above, I just cleared out the datatable, and passed that into the datagrid. This kept all my properties I set on the datagridview column.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.datagridview.Rows)
{
    datagridview.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem I tried with many solutions.

In the end I realized that we can't clear the DataGridView if we use it's property "DGV.Datasource" because DGV takes its data from the dataset so you need to clear the DataTable rows

```
Dataset.Tables["TableName"].Rows.Clear();
```

If you use this function in the Load of the Form you need to add a condition

```
if (DataSet.Tables["TableName"] !=null)    
    Dataset.Tables["TableName"].Rows.Clear();
```

or you will get this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: use this condition  if (DataSet.Tables["TableName"] !=null)                                     Dataset.Tables["TableName"].Rows.Clear();