# Not getting gridview1.Rows.Clear() option in VS 2010 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I clear rows in DataGridView with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184402/how-can-i-clear-rows-in-datagridview-with-c)

I am using gridview to show details of some of my data. The flow is like this: when a dropdown value is changed, the data in the gridview is bound according to the selected value. Now when there is no data corresponding to that value, I need to clear the gridview. For this I use:

```
gridview1.Rows.Clear()
```

But when I compile my code, an error is generated:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for
'Clear' and no extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' could be found (are you missing
a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have also given the reference:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

Now how should I clear the gridview?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry to say but i think i have clearly mentioned my error and i cannot see that error anywhere in the thread u have referenced. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the `GridView` with `null`, or with a new `DataSource`.

```
gridview1.DataSource = null;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: @tim thank you. this solved the issue. but i still wanted to know why that option is not available.

Comment: @DollyDar: Because this is ASP.NET and not Winforms. The [`GridViewRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.aspx) does not have a `Clear` method as it's Winforms relative [`DataGridViewRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.clear.aspx). You always have to rebind the DataSource to the DataBoundControl in ASP.NET. By the way, thank Yograj Gupta not me.

Comment: oh yes. thanks yograj gupta and tim for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can bind grid view to empty datatable
and set value `"EmptyDataText"` property if you want to display some text when there is no record in grid view.