# Setting DataSource of DataGridView to null/false removes all default settings of DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, .net-3.5

In DataGridView, when I set `dataGridView.DataSource = null` or `dataGridView.DataSource = false`, it removes all default setting (properties) I have set.

How it looks without setting `DataSource` to `null` (See `Mark` column is actually `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`)

[image]

After setting `DataSource` to `null` or `false` and load items in DataGridView:

[image]

See here `Id` column is visible which I set visible false by default (from properties window). Also the `Mark` column became `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` from `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

What I actually want: I just want to clear all rows (in other words I want to set DataGridView blank after removing records from database). Like this one:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried dataGridView.Rows.Clear()?

Comment: @diogod - Clear() gives me [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6184402/1369235) because there is a column  (Mark) with `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Comment: and datatable.clear that is suggested on the error link?

Comment: @diogod - Ok that works fine. But now my only question is: Why setting `DataSource` to `null`/`false` removes all default settings. Thanks.

Comment: How are you assigning your datasource..?? What are you using in background??

Comment: I assume your datagridview has `.AutoGenerateColumns = True` and `datagridview` generate all columns again. Plus your predefined columns must be still there...

Comment: @Fabio - Nope I set `AutoGenerationColumns = false` while assigning DataSource.

Comment: Have you predefined columns of datagridview? or generate them in code?

Comment: @Fabio - Yes I have predefined it.

Comment: Then `DataSource = null` will not reset them and their properties. Again i think that your `.AutoGenerateCOlumns = true` or your setting it to `False` not executed...

Comment: @Fabio - Ah! You are correct. I commented `AutoGenerateColumns = false`. Looks like I need more *Coffee*. BTY, can you please convert your comment in answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `datagridview.DataSource = null` will not reset/change a columns or their properties

If you have a predefined columns(in designer) then,
please, check that line of code `datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns = False` will execute properly...

Because if `datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns = True` more columns will be added to predefined columns of datagridview