# why i cannot clear the rows in the datagridview control?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I was doing this test, I need to re-load the datagridview with data every 4 seconds and the data was coming from a database.

so i'v created a **timer** control by code and added an event handler to the `tick` event. Then in the tick event

```
void t1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dt = Product.GetAllProductsBasicInfo();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

}
```

above code works but when I move

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

before

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

it will throw a run time error saying the rows cannot be cleared, I want to know why it throws this error, typically Clear() clears the datagridview?

thanks

Comment: try to check this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184402/how-can-i-clear-rows-in-datagridview-with-c)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> typically Clear() clears the datagridview?

Yes, unless it has a DataSource, which in your case, it does.

So try clearing the source of the data instead:

```
dt.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: Thank your answer where the best for me, but I got problem I am binding my `datagridview` from `datatable` when `dt.Rows.Clear();` its clear all rows except the header that cause to me a problem since I am changing the binding `datasource`  that why I am clearing rows I tried all other suggestion but same problem please whould you mind to help me clearing all row including the header rows which also came from binding source

Comment: @sam You would have to post it as a new question. Make sure to document it so that it's reproducible by your audience.

Comment: okay ill make new post and explain my problem again thanks :)

Comment: can I clear the ros within datagridview bounded form data source without clearing the datatable ?

Comment: @sam No, unless you can make a DataView out of the DataTable that filters out all the rows.

Comment: its clear all rows except the header that cause to me a problem : it is because you have added the header manually.