# Cannot clear this list

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting the above error message on a DataGridView. This dgv is bound to a datatable. Below is the code that I use to check it.

```
                If TypeOf ctl Is DataGridView Then
                    Dim ctl1 As DataGridView = DirectCast(ctl, DataGridView)

                    If Not IsNothing(ctl1.DataSource) = False Then
                        ctl1.DataSource = Nothing
                    Else
                        ctl1.Rows.Clear()
                    End If
                End If
```

The code is taking the Else branch so I don't know why it's throwing this exception.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether `Rows` is assigned?

Comment: Hmm, double negatives, always a bad idea.  Remove " = False".

Comment: Try `ctl1.DataSource = Nothing` no if/else statement needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it is taking the else branch?

If the DGV is databound the the Rows.Clear() will throw an exception.

Try changing the if statement to

```
If IsNothing(ctl1.Datasource) = False Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the rows to what `ctl1` `DataGridView` is pointing to instead of clearing `ctl1` directly:

```
myDataTable.Rows.Clear()
```

See [why i cannot clear the rows in the datagridview control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490151/why-i-cannot-clear-the-rows-in-the-datagridview-control)

Or,

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/332902/how-to-clear-datagridview-in-csharp