# Why dataGridView.Rows.Clear() doesn't work?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForms application with a DataGridView set with default settings to allow users to add rows. But I want to remove rows programmatically as well.

When I run the function `dataGridView.Rows.Clear()` nothing happens - the rows remain in the DataGridView.

I got as far as changing the edit mode, removing the data source, and refreshing:

```cs
dataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView.Refresh();
dataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
```

But still, the rows added by the user are visible in the DGV. How can I remove these rows?,

EDIT:
Screenshot of the DGV:

[image: DGV]

Comment: sounds like [this might be a fitting duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492425/5174469)

Comment: Does the DGV actually have a DataSource? Because, if it does, setting `dataGridView.DataSource = null;` will delete everything, since the DGV has nothing to show. `.Rows.Clear()`  becomes redundant. How is your DGV setup? E.g., do you also have unbound Columns? Do you have shared Rows? Is it linked to a DataSet with relations? etc.

Comment: Could you add a screen-snip of your `DataGridView`or a paste a **Control-Alt-PrintScreen** capture of your main form? Also, make sure the `DataGridView.VirtualMode` property is set to `False`.

Comment: @IVSoftware Virtual mode is set to false, I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: @Jimi - DGV is loaded empty, without any data source. Users are supposed to enter data themselves. I have to columns added in Visual Studio editor, not programatically.

Comment: Since the DGV has no DataSource, why are you setting `dataGridView.DataSource = null;`? -- There's something else you're not saying here, because - given the setup you have described - calling `dataGridView.Rows.Clear();`  **IS** going to remove the Rows, doesn't matter if the ComboBox Column has a DataSource set (this assuming `dataGridView` is the *right* Control you're trying to clear). --  You should also specify when/where the `Clear()` method is called.

Comment: @Jimi I agree that `dataGridView.Rows.Clear()` _should_ do the trick and whatever is making it not do that is elsewhere in the code than shown here. TK-421 it is for this very reason that I suggested the shortest way to get where you want is to go ahead and set up the `DataSource`.  And when the time comes to make it a web or mobile app, you'll be glad that your UI and the data it holds are separate concerns  :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try iterating through dataGridViewError.Rows collection and remove one by one?

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewError.Rows)   
 {
  try
  {
    dataGridViewError.Rows.Remove(row);
  }
  catch (Exception) { } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, and it is not working. I even tried running just:
```foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows){ MessageBox.Show("row"); }``` and that didn't show any messages.

Comment: This is a poor solution.  You shouldn't modify the collection during a for-each: the indexes get messed up.  The empty try-catch is a code smell.  Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment . this is the first solution came to my mind. now i know the problem with it

Answer (score 1):

Your question is **Why dataGridView.Rows.Clear() doesn't work** and the answer is that your posted code is acting on the `DataSource` property but that property doesn't appear to be set up (or utilized) correctly.

First you need a class that will act as a **Model** for a Row (in other words it declares the columns you want to have in your `DataGridView`). Making properties `{get;set;}` means the user will be able to edit those properties in the `DataGridView`.

```
public class Record
{
    public string Licznic { get; set; }
    public string Procent { get; set; }
}
```

What makes `DataGridView` easy to use is that it's designed to configure itself **automatically** based on this class. Just make a `BindingList<Record>` and attach it to the `DataSource` property by overriding `OnHandleCreated` in your Main Form class:

```
BindingList<Record> DataSource = new BindingList<Record>();
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);

    // Attach the DataSource to your DataGridView
    // Now changes to source records refresh in the view.
    dataGridView1.DataSource = this.DataSource;

    // Adding one or more records will generate the columns.
    DataSource.Add(new Record { Licznic = "ABC123", Procent = "XYZ" });
    DataSource.Add(new Record { Licznic = "DEF456", Procent = "PQR" });

    // Use string indexer to get a column
    dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.Licznic)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.Licznic)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

If you run this code, you get this:

[image: generated columns]

When the clear button on the UI is clicked, it now acts on the `DataSource` not the UI and you will find this very effective:

```
private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSource.Clear();
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment that the data grid view is loaded empty, make this minor change in `OnHandleCreated` to achieve that initial state:

```
// Adding one or more records will generate the columns.
DataSource.Add(new Record { Licznic = "", Procent = "" });

// Based on your comment that the DataGridView is "Loaded Empty"
// you would want to clear this record immediately after the
// automatic configuration has taken place.
DataSource.Clear();
```

Comment: I tested it to make sure that `Clear` still works after user adds new records.  If you'd like to experiment with this code, I put the sample [here](https://github.com/IVSoftware/data_grid_view_clear.git) on GitHub.