# Vb.Net Dataset table = New DataTable

Tags: vb.net, dataset, equals

I came across one programming issue that I have tried to solve it as follows:

```
dsDataSet.Tables("promotion") = New DataTable.
```

But Unfortunately this does not work because error: property 'Item' is read only

Is there away to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

The Tables collection of a DataSet could be modified using the Add, Remove methods

```
dsDataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable("promotion"))
```

of course, the line above requires that the collection doesnt already contain a table named "promotion". If you have already a table named "promotion" in your dataset then you need to remove it before adding the new one

```
dsDataSet.Tables.Remove("promotion")
dsDataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable("promotion"))
```

Comment: Actually I am filling the table using the function dataset.Fill(). Your suggestion is right if I defined a datatable and fill it. But I am just filling the table inside the dataset.

Comment: I don't understand what is your goal here. If you want to fill a dataset then the table is automatically created in the fill process. If you want to create a new table, of course, you need to fill it for example with DataTable.Load(DataReader). Please explain better what are your ultimate objective here.

Comment: I fill table without problem. But sometimes I need to reload the data again. When I reload the data again I will need to clear all the records in the datatable and refill again. But when I use the dgv.rows.clear it says this list cannot be cleared. So, instead of clearing the data from the datatable I tried something like dsDataSet.Tables("promotion") = New DataTable. but this does not work. So is there away to clear the datatable as making it New datatable

Comment: dgv.Rows.Clear refers to a DataGridView? If so you need to call Clear on the DataTable not the grid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184402/how-can-i-clear-rows-in-datagridview-with-c