# How to remove all DataGridView rows on form load?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How can I remove all the datagridview rows except the column headers?

I tried:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.clear();
```

but it does not work.

I tried to loop over the rows and use the `RemoveAt` method, but it does not remove all rows:

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\myserver;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id as [#], description as [Description], unit as [Unit], amount as [Amount], unitPrice as [Unit Price], total as [Total] FROM tbl_poMaterials", con);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    DataTable tb = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(tb);
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tb;

    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 30;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 660;

    for (int i = 0; i < tb.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        tb.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "but It does not work", what happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView.Clear()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744882/datagridview-clear)

Answer (score 19):

I use

```
dataGridViewResult.Rows.Clear();
```

to clear every rows without delete columns.

Comment: This worked for me, my datagridview is filled manually not with datatable or another source

Comment: thanks and this works fine.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

```
do
{
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewError.Rows)
   {
      try
      {
        dataGridViewError.Rows.Remove(row);
      }
      catch (Exception) { }
   }
} while (dataGridViewError.Rows.Count > 1);
```

Comment: Strange , why for and for each loops not working and this one works ? But good thing is it works !

Comment: Thanks from a a year and a few months later. I tried using a `foreach` on the Rows collection on my DGV but I was getting an exception when it'd try to delete that one "blank" row. If I added a check for nulls, it was only deleting every other row? This works, though.

Answer (score 11):

You need to clear the DataSource or DataTable and not the datagridview.

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.Refresh();
```

or

```
dataTable.Clear();
dataGridView.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 4):

For the same issue I tried several ways but could not succeed. As said in one of the answers:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    myDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
}
```

will actually delete the row but the next row gets shifted to previous row ! So, the above approach deletes half of the number of rows ! Hence, you need to repeat the action till it becomes zero!

Alternatively, tried deleting from the last row to the first. It works!

```
for(int i = myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    myDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your grid is bound to a DataTable or some other DataSource then you need to clear it, not the grid, otherwise the Rows.clear() method is the right and best way to do it.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < tb.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                tb.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }

Comment: You have your datagridview bound to a datatable, so clear the datatable : tb.clear()

Answer (score 2):

Make row and column count zero and refresh data set.

```
dataGrid.Rows.Count = 0;
```

`dataGrid.Refresh();`

Answer (score 1):

//this should work

```
int rowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Your solution didnt work because , everytime when the for loop checks for the condition `i < rowCount`, the `rowCount` would have already decreased by one as a result of `dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)`. So only half of the rows would have been deleted.

Comment: Please use 4 spaces in front of each code line to get a code block. Also "your solution" is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

`while(dataGridView1.Rows.Count >1)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
}`

Comment: Should be while(dataGridView1.Rows.Count >0)

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowCount = dtg.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dr = dtg.Rows[i];
            dtg.Rows.Remove(dr);
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is obvious, but "clear" isn't capitalized (it should be) in the example given. That should throw a build error and prevent you from running it, but since it's not clear what error you're having, this may be what's going on.