# Deleting all the data from a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Why doesn't this work?

```
    //::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    private void uxClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearDGV();
    }
    void clearDGV()
    {
        // remove selected rows 
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in uxDGV.Rows)
        {
            uxDGV.Rows.Remove(row);
        } 
    }
    //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

The DGV is not bound and the user has typed information into it.

Error I get is `InvalidOperationException was unhandled  Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted.`

**EDIT**

ok - thanks to Steve etc for encouraging me to find the answer for myself!!

```
uxChargeBackDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I clear rows in DataGridView with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184402/how-can-i-clear-rows-in-datagridview-with-c)

Comment: You can't loop on a collection using foreach and inside the loop remove items from the same collection

Comment: Try iterating backwards through the items and deleting each one as you go. for (int x = uxDGV.Rows.Count; x > 0; x--)

Comment: @SeanBright ...that question looks like it is in connection with a _bound_ datagridview; mine does not have a datasource.

Comment: @roymustang86 - clearing all the rows is what I'd like; what is the syntax?

Comment: @Fermin see Steve's comment - I don't think this is going to work

Comment: @Steve - looks like one of those where I'm given loads of comments that hint at the answer in a sort of "work it out for yourself" way ! I'm sure you all know the answer.

Comment: @whytheq David Hall's answer is the syntax to clear the rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView.Clear()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744882/datagridview-clear)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fortunately the `DataGridView` provides a method to do this for us, simply call `Clear` like so:

```
uxDGV.Rows.Clear();
```

---

The reason you were getting your error was because you were trying to remove the uncommitted new row. (the error is actually nice and informative once you know the problem!)

The new row is identified by the boolean `IsNewRow` property on `DataGridView` rows.

In your code you also had the problem of iterating over a collection as you modify it. So you would have needed to do something like below, where we iterate forwards but remove at zero each time:

```
int rowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
for (int n = 0; n < rowCount; n++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[0].IsNewRow == false)
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
}
```