# to clear the data of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a tabcontrol, it has 9 tabpage collection each tabpage has a datagridview and a searchbox.

```
 private void txtsrchesd_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (txtsrchesd.Text == "")
    {

    }
    else
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=JAY\J_SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=FillingDatabase;User ID=jay;Password=pass1234";
        string query = " SELECT * FROM esd_view  where department like '" + txtsrchesd.Text + "%' order by department ";

        SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, scon);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sql = new SqlDataAdapter(query, scon);
        sql.Fill(dt);
        sql.Dispose();

        dgesd.DataSource = dt;

        memoDatabaseDataSetBindingSource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

    }
}
private void txtsrchope_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtsrchope.Text == "")
    {

    }
    else
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=JAY\J_SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=FillingDatabase;User ID=jay;Password=pass1234";
        string query = " SELECT * FROM operations_view  where department like '" + txtsrchope.Text + "%' order by department ";

        SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, scon);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sql = new SqlDataAdapter(query, scon);
        sql.Fill(dt);
        sql.Dispose();

        dgoper.DataSource = dt;

        memoDatabaseDataSetBindingSource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

    }
}
```

The output of the other datagridview appears on the other datagridview , how can I clear the output of the datagridview as I clear what I type on my searchbox

hope you understand , thank you for the help

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: @S.Akbari , how can i clear the output of the datagridview as i clear what i type on my searchbox ??

Comment: So when either of your textboxes have no value, you want your datagridview to have no data? Try looking at this answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137591/how-to-clear-a-data-grid-view

Answer (score -1):

When you are checking with:

```
{
    if (txtsrchope.Text != "")
    {}
    .....
}
```

In the else part you don't need to fire the same query as when:

```
txtsrchop.text ==""
```

You can replace your else part by this code:

```
else
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=JAY\J_SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=FillingDatabase;User ID=jay;Password=pass1234";
        string query = " SELECT * FROM operations_view  ";

    SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, scon);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sql = new SqlDataAdapter(query, scon);
    sql.Fill(dt);
    sql.Dispose();

    dgoper.DataSource = dt;

    memoDatabaseDataSetBindingSource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

}
```