# Unable to remove DataGrid rows / clear table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I trying to clear the `DataGrid` table but am unable to do so. I have the following code

```
carGrid.RowCount = 0;
carGrid.Rows.Clear();
carGrid.DataSource = null;
```

which gives me this error:

> Additional information: RowCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control.

If I remove the line

```
carGrid.RowCount = 0;
```

from the code I get that error:

> Additional information: Cannot clear this list.

Comment: Delete first two lines.

Comment: i have tried but same error. i bind grid with datatable after giving null to datasource. but same error

Comment: //carGrid.RowCount = 0;
                    //carGrid.Rows.Clear();
                    carGrid.DataSource = null;
                    carGrid.DataSource = BindGridView();

Comment: Could you try this answer? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137591/how-to-clear-a-data-grid-view)

Comment: So clear datasource - datatable.

Comment: while (dataGridView1.RowCount > 1)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
}   is working....Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear a data grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137591/how-to-clear-a-data-grid-view)

Comment: I reformatted/reformulated the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

To clear data from a `DataGridView`, you just need to call the following;

```
carGrid.Rows.Clear();
```

You could also try something like this;

```
DataTable data = (DataTable)carGrid.DataSource;
if (data != null) 
{
    data.Clear();
}
```

Comment: while (dataGridView1.RowCount > 1)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
}     its working