# How do delete All rows at DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, delete-row

this is code :

```
         BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();


       DataTable tbl(string sql)
        {

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionstring);
        OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "tbl");
        return ds.Tables["tbl"];
        }
 void GetData()
  {

   bs.DataSource = Class1.tbl("select USER_ID   ,EMP_NAME as pName,EMP_MOBILE from TBLUSERS");
            datagridview1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "USER_ID";
            datagridview1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "pName";
            datagridview1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "EMP_MOBILE";
            datagridview1.DataSource = bs;
 }

  void ClearAllRows()
    {
          datagridview1.Rows.Clear();
   //The error occurs here 
    }
```

The error occurs here
How do delete All rows at DataGridView ? 
my DataGridView  is BindingSource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView.Clear()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744882/datagridview-clear)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can set your `DataGridView` `DataSource` to `null`  instead of clearing the Rows.

**Replace this :**

```
datagridview1.Rows.Clear();
```

**With Following:**

```
datagridview1.DataSource=null;
```

Comment: Am not sure why `datagridview1.Rows.Clear()` is required

Comment: Yes you are right, i was in a context of clearing the rows , as soon as DataSource is set to null , Gridview becomes EMPTY. Thanks for your valuable Point and i have made changes to my answer, Thank you.

Comment: This does not work when your Datagridview is setup with a 'bindingsource' in designview.  You must handle the bindingsource directly.  Then clear the datatable, or whatever you need to clear.
`Dim bs As BindingSource = DirectCast(dgvGrid1.DataSource, BindingSource)
        Dim ds As DataSet = DirectCast(bs.DataSource, DataSet)
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
        dt.Rows.Clear()`

Comment: **The original line `datagridview1.Rows.Clear();` is what works IF** you manipulated data without `BindingSource`! E.g: smth like `dgv.Rows[index].Cells["Column1"].Value = "Column1";`

Answer (score 1):

```
while (dataGridView1.Rows.Count>0)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Do This Code

```
if(dgvItemDetails.Rows.Count>0) {
    do
    {
        dgvItemDetails.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    while (dgvItemDetails.Rows.Count > 0);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can as well delete directly at the DataTable as, by definition, both the DataTable and the DataGrid are binded. I like the approach where I know exactly what I'm deleting, so I suggest storing the selection of rows you wish to delete at a DataRow[].

```
DataRow[] dataRows;

.....

dataRows = myDS.Tables["MyTable"].Select("Id = " + 200); //or any criteria that returns the row collection you wish to Delete
foreach (DataRow row in dataRows) { row.Delete(); }
```