# Clear DataGrid for new search result in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to clear the DataGrid for new result view but I couldn't. Is there any problem of my writing those code or anything else?  Please help me on this. Here is the code:

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sid = txtsid.Text;
        string subject = cmbsubject.Text;
        string term = txtterm.Text;
        string year = cmbyear.Text;
        string stclass = cmbclass.Text;

        string connection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\sms.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        string queryAll = "SELECT * FROM Result WHERE sid='"+sid+"' OR term='"+term+"' OR subject='"+subject+"' OR class='"+stclass+"' OR year = '"+year+"'";


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryAll, con);

        try
        { 
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            DataTable dataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dataset); 

            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataset;

            // dgResult is the changed name of the DataGridView
            dgResult.DataSource = bs;
            sda.Update(dataset);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex));
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745070/4180382

Comment: @OleEHDufour I have already tried those. But no results. Previous result still remains on the data grid

Comment: `dgResult.DataSource = null` ?

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: avoid using string concatenation to create queries, use parameters.